# Outputing the predefined variables `make -R` references?

Tags: gnu-make

According to the docs on `make` there is a `-R` switch,

```
-R, --no-builtin-variables
            Don't define any built-in variables.
```

How can I find those builtin variables and their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the closest you can get

```
env -i make -rp | grep -v '^#' | grep ' = '
```

That prints out the database less the rules, in an environment that isn't pristine result in what I believe is just the builtin variables.